# How to stop VBA Timestamp code to update all cells that have this function on all rows everytime a change is made on some row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Later edit: I now realize that it is because users insert rows and I think that is causing (all) the timestamp cells to update at every insert. Not sure how to overcome this issue.

Basically, what I would like to do is for the timestamp to occur in cell A2 when someone fills in column P2 or column R2 on the same row without impacting other rows.

Based on the wording above, I would like cell A2 to contain the timestamp of the edited P2 or R2 column and keep that timestamp if P2 or R2 remain unmodified.

I used the below code in an Excel table but for some reason, when updating cell P / R on whatever row, the timestamp in cell A[row] changes to the last edit timestamp for all the A cells.

My goal would be for it work row by row and for it not to influence all the rest of the rows.

Appreciate any help I can get.

```
Function Timestamp(Reference As Range)
If Reference.Value <> "" Then
Timestamp = Format(Now, "m/dd/yy hh:mm")
Else
Timestamp = ""
End If
End Function
```

My headers come first and then in column A2 I use the formula `=IF(AND(P2="",R2<>""),Timestamp(R2),Timestamp(P2))`

Answer (score 0):

You should tried to disable automatic calculation in options:

[image]

And then write vba code that specifies formulas should update when there is activity in you target columns with something like: `Application.CalculateFullRebuild`